# Building a quick Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I would like to create and test (proof of concept) an Azure Data Factory. I have an Azure sandbox at work and built a rg with a storage account, but to create a SQL Server to be at the Azure end it would cost a lot! I cant justify that cost.
Is there anyway or any links to build a data factory to a free database in azure.
The idea is to scrape data off the web, into the data factory and then into an existing Datalake, but this is just my first step.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose an Azure SQL Database and set the service tiers to the most basic ones (no support, local redundance, etc.). Check the [Azure Pricing Calculator](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/) to have an idea of cost

I create one to study data factory and it cost me aroud 5 euros/month